# Passing array to function parameter

Tags: php, function

Is it ok to pass an array in a function argument? For example,

```
function something() 
{
if ($this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data)) {
$data = array(
    'user_id' => $this->db->insert_id();
    'first_name' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
    );


 if ($activated)
            $this->create_profile($data);
            return array( //not sure why i'm returning this
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'first_name' => $first_name,
                        'last_name' => $last_name,
    }                   );
    return NULL;
    }
```

and then pass that to

```
    private function create_profile($data)
    {
    return $this->db->insert( $this->profile_table_name, $data )
    }
```

the script is from a codeigniter plugin which I modified, so I'm trying not to butcher it too much.

Comment: because i don't yet fully understand it :(

Comment: when you get all your code working the way you want it, be sure to edit your post to include it. As it is now, there's some  weird curly braces inside the `return array(` and probably a missing `{` after `if ($activated)`.  I started to do the edits myself, but the intent is unclear where that missing `{` is.

Comment: thanks! In the original code there is no { after `if ($activated)` perhaps I should add it. hmm i dont see the weird curly braces in the return array. are u sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to pass an array to a function.  Many of PHP's own built-in `array_*()` functions receive array parameters and then return arrays.

And as for returning an array from the function -- that's an excellent way to return multiple values from a single function.

Comment: ooh I see! thx. can i instead return `$data`? instead of each value?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it ok to pass an array in a function argument?** => **YES!**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return multiple values, an array is one way of doing that.

You could also return an object, just instantiate `stdClass` and set the properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to pass an `array` as a parameter as well as it is okay to return an `array` as a result. In `PHP` we do it all the times.

It is also okay to pass and return arrays in other languages... like in `Python` they do it often, e.g. `process_parameters(*parameters)`.

It is even okay if you pass an object! Or return an object... Like so:

```
$dbConnection = get_db_connection('mysql'); // $dbConnection is an instance of MySQLDbConnection now
```